# How do we read multiple entries on the same line?

Tags: lazarus

I want to input two or multiple entries on the same line. 
How do I get the program to read 2  or more entries?

```
begin
   Write(' Input student namer and his/her score for the math test ');
   readln(names[i],mark[i]);
   Writeln;
end;
```

Comment: Using `ReadLn` for string parameters you can not. Read whole line and parse it: `ReadLn(line); sscanf(line, '%s %d', [@name, @score]);` (`line, name: string; score: Integer;` `sscanf` function is from the `SysUtils` unit)

Comment: Or put the numeric value first.

Comment: Thanks.I have never thought of that!.